# Why am I getting an Illegal instruction (core dumped) error when attempting to run conpot in a vm?

Tags: 22.04, python

Attempts at running conpot is giving me a illegal instruction (core dumped) error.

I am running an Ubuntu 22.04.4 server and I am attempting to run a conpot on it. It was working this morning and I went to boot up another vm from the same ISO and now when I attempt to start conpot. (conpot -f --template default). I get an illegal instruction (core dumped) error. I am running Python 3.10.12.